# Definition recognized as a function-declaration

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

I've got a local variable inside a function:

```
vector<extend_t> newExtends( extend_alloc_t( alloc ) );
```

Unfortunately it gets recognized as a function definition. How do I prevent that ?

Comment: This is known as "most vexing parse". Inserting redundant `(...)` might help.

Comment: Use `{ ... }` instead of `( ... )`

Comment: @ChrisMM: Lol, I just went under the shower and had the same idea. But thanks anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/most-vexing-parse/info

Comment: `it gets recognized as a function definition`, I think you mean *declaration* ?

Comment: It will not be recognised as a function definition, since there is no block statement (the bit between `{` and `}` when implementing a function).   It may - depending on what `extend_alloc_t(alloc)` is - be recognised as a function *declaration*.    (For reference, a function definition is a kind of function declaration, so all function definitions are also declarations - but not all function declarations are definitions).

Comment: @ChrisMM Wouldn't that invoke the `std::initializer_list` overload of the vector constructor?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, didn't think of that. Might depend on the type of `extend_alloc_t`?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: Use copy-initialization with `=` instead, as in:

```
auto newExtends = std::vector<extend_t>( extend_alloc_t( alloc ) );
```

<sub>[Note that actual copying should be elided]</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use`{}`

```cpp
std::vector<extend_t> newExtends = std::vector<extend_t>{extend_alloc_t(alloc)};
```

Comment: Unfortunately using curly braces `{}` doesn''t work exactly the same because that will invoke the `std::initializer_list` overload of the constructor.

Comment: There is no reason to use both `auto newExtends = ...` **and** curly braces. The former is enough, and the latter is risky, since the behavior changes depending on what `extend_t` and `extend_alloc_t` are.